# Attached code throws java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect data check for given .dat file

Tags: java, inputstream, zlib

I have a dat file which is encoded using flate.
I am trying to decode that file using InflateInputStream which is based on ZLib library.
But using the below sample gives me

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect data check
```

The .dat file is kept [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-knnJ8nfTAqa1FvSEoyRVB6NDA/view?usp=sharing)

Code:-

```
    int buflength = 1;
    byte[] buf = new byte[buflength];
    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(INPUT_DIRECTORY + INPUT_FILE));
    Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
    //decompresser.setInput(buf);
    InflaterInputStream ifis = new InflaterInputStream(is,decompresser,buflength);



    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + OUTPUT_FILE));
    /*Deflater compressor = new Deflater();
    DeflaterOutputStream dfos = new DeflaterOutputStream(os, compressor, buflength);
    */

    int counter = 0;
    //long bytesToCopy = 40000;
    int bytesThisRead = 0;
    long bytesCopied = 0;

    while ((bytesThisRead = ifis.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) 
    {
        os.write(buf, 0, bytesThisRead);
        System.out.println((counter++) + " " + bytesThisRead);

        //bytesToCopy -= bytesThisRead;
        bytesCopied += bytesThisRead;
    }
```

I tried debugging the code in InflatterInputStream library, there i could find that there is some issue with reading the last byte in the raw data stream.
(keep buf size as 1 then error comes after last byte)

Here for this data file , size of the raw stream is 11005 wheras for decoded stream is 36963.

So how to fix such issues in which last byte is corrupt?

Comment: _Of course_ the error comes after the last byte, since it needs that byte to perform the integrity check. That doesn't mean that that last byte is the one that's corrupt.

Comment: @Mark so what needs to be done at my end to process that last byte correctly and my code doesnt throw any exception?

Comment: Give it correct data. The integrity check is working properly, indicating that your compressed data was corrupted somewhere along the way, or not generated correctly in the first place.

Comment: @MarkAdler what did you do at your end that made integrity check to work properly?

The thing is, i have to process the .dat file in this form, is there any workaround that you can suggest to me, so that this corrupted file could be processed succesfully?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't work. The .dat file was corrupted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever made that zlib stream (UL_obj_11_0_raw.dat) did not make a zlib stream.  The Adler-32 check at the end is supposed to be stored in big-endian order, but they stored the correct check value in the wrong order, little-endian.

Comment: The catch is, the place from where i brought this .dat file, it need to be processed in the same form..... So as a starter i tried using ByteBuffer and providing it a byte array as buffer with ByteOrder as BigEndian.... but still no luck.
Can you please help me out in this case, like how can i do  something which would process inflate the .dat file in its present form succesfully?
Thanks in advance Mark

Comment: a) You need to tell whoever that .dat file came from that it is _wrong_.  b) Until they fix it, you can reverse the last four bytes, and only the last four bytes, of the stream before feeding to inflate.

Comment: Hi Mark,
I had few files on which the option (b) that you suggested works but there is one file in which it still fails. Have kept it at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-knnJ8nfTAqblV0WEczY2hLUmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For that one, the Adler-32 check at the end is just plain wrong, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: i am kind of stuck at this issue now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496869/read-data-from-infaltterinputstream-without-inflatting.

can you please help me out here as to how can i bypass reading from InflatterInputStream without inflatting the underlying data as such?

Comment: Is there some workaround which i can apply on the file to which adler-32 check was plain wrong?

Comment: You could ignore the error and hope for the best. When the Adler-32 check does not match, either the data is wrong, the Adler-32 check is wrong, or both. There is no way to know which.

Comment: is there a way to read the contents of the inflater stream without uncompressing i.e reading the raw data and saving it to a byte array

Comment: Saving what exactly to a byte array?

Comment: 1) I want read the raw data in the stream, without inflatting the stream and save the data in a byte array so that ByteOrder could be modified used for computation in Adler-32. 2) How can i read the complete raw stream and skip the adler-32 check at the end instead?

Comment: 1) You can't find out where the end of the stream is without decompressing it.  2) You can skip the first two bytes (zlib header) and do a raw inflate of the compressed data, setting `nowrap` true when creating the inflator.

Comment: 1)I need to save the raw data i.e compressed data in byte array, all i have is the InflaterInputStream object, so now is it possible to do so?
2) If i have a fileinputstream object then skipping the first two bytes in the stream and then creating the inflater using nowrap option works marvelously, but the issue is i have just the inflaterinputstream object using which neither i could skip nor set it's  modified inflater, so in this case how do i skip adler-32 check........

Sorry for lot of trouble.....Thanks in Advance

Comment: To skip the Adler-32 check, simply skip the next four bytes in the stream.

Comment: I didn't get you, skipping first 4 bytes in inflater inputstream i suppose but thats not working...Could you elaborate?

Comment: No, the last four bytes.  Once you have completed raw inflation, skip the next four bytes in the stream.

Comment: But if i dont know the length of the stream that i am working with then how do i know when the last 4 bytes came in during read call?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94631/discussion-between-sumit-kumar-saha-and-mark-adler).

Comment: could you please provide a small sample code, as i am failing to understand what you are trying to say My sample code:- byte[] buf = getBuffer(true); long bytesCopied = 0; int bytes = 0; while ((bytes = is.read(buf)) != -1) { os.write(buf, 0, bytes); bytesCopied += bytes; System.out.println("1 " + bytesCopied); } return bytesCopied