# Read data from InflaterInputStream without inflating

Tags: java, stream, zlib

I have a data stream which is flate encoded.
Adler-32 check requires the data to be in Big-Endian form whereas the data stream i have is in little endian form.

I tried using Google-Guava's API

```
 byte[] filedata=ByteStreams.toByteArray(inflaterInputStream);
```

as i needed byte manipulation in case the data is in little-endian format.
But during conversion of data to byte array , stream gets inflated. Hence "incorrect data check" is thrown.

So How can i read data from InflaterInputstream without inflating the data and then modify it before inflating so that Adler-32 check passes otherwise it throws data integrity check.

I have a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348192/attached-code-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-incorrect-data-check-for-given) to which Mark Adler had responded but i am now stuck at my above mentioned issue.

EDIT:
The `inflaterInputStream` is created this way:

```
int buflength = 4096; 
byte[] buf = new byte[buflength]; 
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)); 
Inflater decompresser = new Inflater(); 
InflaterInputStream inflatterInputStream = new InflaterInputStream(is,decompresser,buflength);
```

Comment: It would probably help if you show how you create the "inflatterInputStream".

Comment: @fishinear
int buflength = 4096;
byte[] buf = new byte[buflength];
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
InflaterInputStream ifis = new InflaterInputStream(is,decompresser,buflength);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [question that you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348192/attached-code-throws-java-util-zip-zipexception-incorrect-data-check-for-given), I understand that you actually have a different problem. There you state that the Adler 32 checksum is in little-endian order, but is supposed to be in big-endian order. You also state that you already have managed to reverse the endianness of the checksum, and that that works fine with most files. That is, **you have already solved the problem that you describe here**. But you still have some files with totally incorrect checksums.

I agree with the advice that Mark Adler himself gives in his comments to that question:

> You need to tell whoever that .dat file came from that it is *wrong*.

and:

> You could ignore the error and hope for the best. When the Adler-32
>   check does not match, either the data is wrong, the Adler-32 check is
>   wrong, or both. There is no way to know which.

Comment: What i told in the other question about solving my problem is via manually editing the contents in .dat file via Hex Editor.
Now in this question, my situation is to do the same to the .dat file via code before decompression starts so that adler-32 check doesnt fail.

Comment: Then follow Adler's advice. Tell the source where you got it from that the checksums are incorrect. And until your source fixes the checksum, ignore the Adler errors. The checksum is just a safety thing, to make sure the file has not been corrupted somewhere in the process.

Comment: is there a way to read the contents of the inflater stream without uncompressing i.e reading the raw data and saving it to a byte array

Comment: I might sound silly here, but how can i explicitly downcast a child class object to its base class i.e from InfalterInputStream to FilterInputStream as doing so would throw classcastexception. 
File I/S and Filter I/S are on the same level but how do i cast a Inflater I/S object to File I/S . Pls help

Comment: You don't need to. Use the variable `is` of type FileInputStream you have already. You could even create a FilterInputStream subclass that sits between the source and  the InflaterInputStream. But again, all of this serves no purpose. Simply ignoring the Adler-32 check is sufficient.

Comment: Oh sry, the code i showed was a sample, the stream object that i have belongs to InflaterInputStream object so now how should i proceed further?

Comment: To proceed further, you should tell to whomever the data comes from that the checksum is incorrect, and then you should ignore the error until they have fixed the checksums.

Comment: I have to make this corrupted stream work. So to ignore the error,i know if i have a fileinputstream object then skipping the first two bytes in the stream and then creating the inflater using nowrap option to create inflaterInputStream object works marvelously, but the issue is i have just the inflaterinputstream object using which neither i could skip nor set it's modified inflater, so in this case how do i skip adler-32 check........Sorry to cause lot of trouble......Thanks in advance